# How to login in postman , using database oauth from Spring

Tags: java, spring, jpa, postman

I am using Spring boot JPA auth with database and when I open localhost and try to use endpoint it asks to login. So in browser login page I can login with username and password but when I try to use Postman and put in Authorization Basic auth with same username and password it's just showing me login page with status 200 OK.How to login in postman?

Comment: Are you sure it's logging in with basic authentication ? I recommend inspecting the outgoing request in the browser, and trying to mimic it. In Firefox, you can copy the request as a curl command, which you can then import into Postman.

Comment: @Hassan Okay i will try use FireFox